# What does "solve crime" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In the following sentence, what is the meaning of "solve crime"?

> The press's role is not to solve crime but to sell newspapers.

1. Does it mean to prevent crime?
2. Does it mean to get at the cause of the crime?
3. Does it mean to find the criminal who have commited the crime?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but I couldn't find this collocation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve is a verb meaning

> to find an answer to a problem

Crime is used as a non-countable noun, meaning

> illegal activities

It is the job of the police, not newspapers, to solve crime

[Solve (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/solve)

[Crime (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crime)